# Is there a way to manage "MachineToApplication" error without having an access to IIS configurations?

Tags: iis

I'm a student and I was given a folder Web folder to use as my project. The problem is what they I try to publish my site to the server I get an error:

> It is an error to use a section registered as
>   allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This
>   error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an
>   application in IIS.

Meaning that my Web folder was not configured as an application folder, therefore my project cannot be rendered (if I got this right? was reading a bit from the internet).

My question is, is there a way to handle this error without having an access to IIS server configurations? From code side of my project?

Error I get:

```
 Configuration Error
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Source Error:


Line 29:         validate="false" />
Line 30:     </httpHandlers>
Line 31:     <authentication mode="None" />
Line 32:     <compilation targetFramework="4.5">
Line 33:       <assemblies>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. IIS configuration system relies on such lock down mechanism, which you cannot break.

More information can be found at

http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/managing-your-configuration-settings/understanding-iis-configuration-delegation